# handle multiple if to get rid of Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I want to handle multiple if conditions to get rid of Cyclomatic Complexity.
please help:

```
BigDecimal totalValue = null;     
 if (null != truckValue && truckValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0 && null != buggyContents && buggyContents.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            totalValue = mainValue.add(truckValue).add(buggyContents);
        } else if (null == buggyContents || buggyContents.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 && null == truckValue || truckValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
            totalValue = mainValue;
        } else if (truckValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 || truckValue == null) {
            totalValue = mainValue.add(buggyContents);
        } else if (buggyContents.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 || buggyContents == null) {
            totalValue = mainValue.add(truckValue).add(buggyContents);
        }
        return totalValue;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with that code? May be give some sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for something like:

```
BigDecimal totalValue = mainValue;
if (null != truckValue && truckValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
    totalValue = totalValue.add(truckValue);
if (null != buggyContents && buggyContents.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
    totalValue = totalValue.add(buggyContents);
return totalValue;
```

probably you want to summarize all non null values? then just remove comparison with zero:

```
BigDecimal totalValue = mainValue;
if (null != truckValue) totalValue = totalValue.add(truckValue);
if (null != buggyContents) totalValue = totalValue.add(buggyContents);
return totalValue;
```

Comment: what to do with last two if conditions when value is less than or null?
Adding values in those conditions too :)

Comment: @user2741923 what do you expect from adding null value in 4th case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to add `truckValue` and `buggyContents` to `mainValue`, but only if the values are neither null nor negative and you want to return the sum, you can do without the whole if-else block by using strems:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

....


public BigDecimal yourMethod(/* whatever */) {
    return Stream.of(truckValue, buggyContents)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .filter(bigDecimal -> bigDecimal.signum() != -1)
                 .reduce(mainValue, BigDecimal::add);
}
```